# Plist file parsing error "'str' object has no attribute 'read'"

Tags: python, plist, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to read a .plist file on Mac OSX with the plistlib. 
Sadly I always get an error when running the script

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johannes/pycharmprojects/adobe-cache-cleaner/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    pl = plistlib.load(fp2)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plistlib.py", line 983, in load
    header = fp.read(32)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

that's my script:

```
import plistlib

fp2 = "/Users/Johannes/Pythonproject/test.plist"

pl = plistlib.load(fp2)
print pl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like ptlistlib ist expecting a file not a string:

```
import plistlib

with open("/Users/Johannes/Pythonproject/test.plist", "rb") as file:
    pl = plistlib.load(file)
    print pl
```

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/plistlib.html

Comment: I tried your suggestions but now I'm running into an UTF-8 Error.

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 8: invalid continuation byte

For the record: I managed to parse the same plist file with python 2.7 and the biplist module :(

Comment: @Johannes Edited... try now

Comment: Works like a Charm now! Thank you! 
What does the "rb" modifier do?